# Mounting android bootloader.img file in linux

Tags: linux, partition, data-recovery, boot-loader, android

I did a backup of android bootloader mtdblock using dd but having trouble to mount it https://transfer.sh/yAxnI/bootloader.img.

```
$ file bootloader.img
bootloader.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xb, start-CHS (0x1,0,1), end-CHS (0x1e0,254,63), startsector 16065, 7711200 sectors

$ sudo fdisk -l bootloader.img
Disk bootloader.img: 8 MiB, 8388608 bytes, 16384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000b99d

Device          Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
bootloader.img1      16065 7727264 7711200  3.7G  b W95 FAT32
```

⠀

```
$ sudo losetup -o 8225280 /dev/loop0 bootloader.img  
$ sudo fsck -fv /dev/loop0


fsck from util-linux 2.35
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/loop0

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

⠀

```
$ sudo mount -t  vfat -o loop,offset=8225280 bootloader.img /mnt/disk/
mount: /mnt/disk: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

⠀

Answer (score 0):

Your backup is incomplete. fdisk reports only 8 MiB of 3,7 GB have been copied.

Comment: so its not possible to extract/mount it?

Comment: Correct. The data is not existant so you cannot access it.